# Send a message to a particular person within a group at random in sharepoint

Tags: designer-workflow

I have a group known as department heads with about 10 names in the group. I would like to be able to send an email from a list created for loan application from different departments without having to send the mail to all members listed in the group using the parallel flow. I would prefer a situation where once the individual dept is selected the mail goes directly to the specified email of the department. Then the loan is being applied from without having to be visible to all members of the group.